# Jmeter does not work on solaris, throws Invalid or corrupt jarfile ApacheJMeter.jar

Tags: java, jmeter, solaris, corruption

I have been running my jmeter instance from Windows and Linux using the same binary files and it works fine.
After I copied the same files to solaris, it throws the error "Invalid or corrupt jarfile ApacheJMeter.jar" and exits.

I do not have the permissions to install the binaries directly using apt-get.

.../apache-jmeter-2.11/bin$ java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar
Invalid or corrupt jarfile ApacheJMeter.jar

OS: Oracle Solaris 10 9/10 s10x_u9wos_14a X86
Jmeter: version 2.11
Java: version 1.6.0_21

Answer (score 0):

Your `ApacheJMeter.jar` file is corrupted. Verify its checksum. On Solaris, you should get this output:

```
$ sum *.jar
48768 26 ApacheJMeter.jar
```

On Linux:

```
$ sum -s *.jar
48768 26 ApacheJMeter.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I had done a simple scp to copy the binary files from its working location on Linux to the Solaris machine. This evidently showed corruption when running sum -s *.jar.

I copied a tar archive of the binaries. Now corruption is not shown by sum command.
.../apache-jmeter-2.11/bin$ sum *.jar
48768 26 ApacheJMeter.jar

However, I still see the corruption error.
.../apache-jmeter-2.11/bin$ java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar
Invalid or corrupt jarfile ApacheJMeter.jar

Comment: try updating your JRE Version.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am not able to upgrade the JRE version presently due to constraints. However, I did try running this from a different machine having a similar environment including same JRE version and it worked. I'm just guessing there is some environment limitation on the machine used earlier.